# Unix File Descriptor Not Found

Tags: file, shell, ksh, file-descriptor

I am having some trouble when using a File descriptor.  The end goal is to be able to use flock for because I am using this script to update a file and it could be run multiple times in parallel and I do not want any collisions. This script is called from another script and passed variables

call script:"call.sh"

```
#!/bin/ksh

scriptDir=/home/Scripts

###other stuff happens####


#Call to replacement script

. $scriptDir/replacement.sh var1 var2
```

replacement script:"replacement.sh"

```
#!/bin/ksh

var1=$1
var2=$2
file=/myfile.doc
exec 300>>$file

flock -x 300

##Replacement logic###
```

When I run call.sh regular or in debug (ksh) I get an error:

```
./call.sh: /replacement.sh[34]: 300: not found
```

At first I though maybe the file descriptor needed to be in the first script too, so I added:

```
exec 300>>$file
```

to the call.sh, but that returned an error like:

```
./call.sh[28]: 300 : not found
```

It would be awesome if someone could explain to me what I am missing!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. You have an invalid space after the `=` in `file= /myfile.doc`
2. ksh only supports single digit fds when used literally. Use `9` instead of `300`.
3. ksh makes non-standard fds non-inheritable. Specifically redirect it to the command.

In all:

```
 #!/bin/ksh
 file=./myfile.doc
 exec 9>>$file
 flock -x 9  9>&9
```

Comment: The space was a typo as I checked my code and it was as you corrected.  I changed the fd to 9 and reran the script and it worked as planned, however after the

    flock -x 9 9>&9

there was an error flock: 9: Bad file descriptor

Comment: I would like to mention, not sure if this matters but the "exec 9>>" in my code changed to all yellow in color.  "9>&9" is also yellow.

Comment: It works for me as posted. Which ksh version do you use?

Comment: PD KSH v5.2.14 99/07/13.2

Comment: Is that the only error you're getting? What if you `exec 8> "$file"; flock -x 8 9>&8`

Comment: Yes that is the only error that I am getting.  The rest of the code is executing, but I don't think that I am actually getting a lock on the file.  The second code that you suggested again returned the error flock: 8: Bad file descriptor.  Also in the exec command it has to be:
    exec 8>> "$file"
or else it totally wipes out the file that I am attempting to write to. (not sure if that has anything to do with it)